# Unable to parse Signature node in XML file

Tags: python, xml-parsing

Am trying to parse "Signature" node in XML and fetch the values for DigestValue and SignatureValue fields in XML. output i see is

```
{'{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}SignedInfo', '{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}SignatureValue'}
```

```
#python parses logic is as below 
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse("MyFile.xml").getroot()

for Signature in root.findall('Signature'):
    attributes = Signature.attrib
    print(attributes.get("xmlns"))
for element in Signature:
    ElementName = element.tag
    ElementValue = Signature.find(ElementName).text
    print(ElementName, ':', ElementValue)
```

Xml file snippet used for parsing is as below

```
<Manifest>
    <Signature
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
            <Reference URI="">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                <DigestValue>YzE5K8Y9+gIrLDqLsvunqquxPxSNTphOadUpEOVbAV4=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>I6iJvmecDy0Cm8jMwv/wlmT0oYkuPRpmieHgbZW8E47yrNLfQhpKUC8zxn9nQarceS6bCN44TeUz7lQz6q53odzfmN6SgpeCaBIXeAeJI7gnmdZO+iXYi3DKZ/3NuEkqpVEpR+hwLeTBWODaIHHm4I0huRlLppN2FC4jJn9qxIaXVQXRb+1PBEavulLlYI8z5dJPatyMDAr0YLTx3FEhYr+i6Jt2YHq0ykZ7mjFQTZQkzo6kQws9+aUaBURbdntJYWwqe7ofTVX0jdd1fD0i3LdYeHkA/+tJQg4BvAQE5HUi2oYdeYrt7sRxV+NN94Tgj7fHOscVZiUsCJew+Ah19g==</SignatureValue>
    </Signature>
</Manifest>
```

Comment: any help here to parse the xml successfully.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access xml elements by its index like below

```py
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse("MyFile.xml").getroot()

print(root[0][0][2][-1].text)
print(root[0][-1].text)
```

**Output**

```
YzE5K8Y9+gIrLDqLsvunqquxPxSNTphOadUpEOVbAV4=

I6iJvmecDy0Cm8jMwv/wlmT0oYkuPRpmieHgbZW8E47yrNLfQhpKUC8zxn9nQarceS6bCN44TeUz7lQz6q53odzfmN6SgpeCaBIXeAeJI7gnmdZO+iXYi3DKZ/3NuEkqpVEpR+hwLeTBWODaIHHm4I0huRlLppN2FC4jJn9qxIaXVQXRb+1PBEavulLlYI8z5dJPatyMDAr0YLTx3FEhYr+i6Jt2YHq0ykZ7mjFQTZQkzo6kQws9+aUaBURbdntJYWwqe7ofTVX0jdd1fD0i3LdYeHkA/+tJQg4BvAQE5HUi2oYdeYrt7sRxV+NN94Tgj7fHOscVZiUsCJew+Ah19g==
```

---

For scalability, If you want to parse through each element to find interested values, please use below program.

This produces same output as above.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse("MyFile.xml").getroot()

def printval(tg):
    if tg.tag.endswith("DigestValue"):
        print(tg.text)
        return
    if tg.tag.endswith("SignatureValue"):
        print(tg.text)
        return
    if len(list(tg))>=1:
        for b in tg:
            printval(b)

printval(root)
```

Comment: Thanks liju. prasing through indexes works fine. Is it possible to parse the values using tags etc. to make it more general and works in all types of XML files having this kind of node.?

Comment: @manju.g.r. I have updated the answer above. Please check.

Comment: Thanks @Liju both the solutions works. but i prefer solution-2 as this is more generic.

Comment: Hi, how can i decode this the output?
YzE5K8Y9+gIrLDqLsvunqquxPxSNTphOadUpEOVbAV4=....
Is this a base64 value?